# how to make different authentication in asp.net c# web form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

we have two part for authentication in web site. the first use in admin and the second use for users to enter to site.when admin authentication in site  and go to user page ,make error.how to create different authentication for those?web config code:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/admin/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: Why complicate it? Read the users permissions on sign on, if they have administrative privileges redirect to "/admin/". You're not gaining anything other than more work attempting it this way

Comment: we read users permissions on sign on.when i use User.Identity.IsAuthenticated then its return true.but this Authenticated for admin.how to make different Authenticated for users?

Comment: @shahroz you have to understand that authentication should only check if that's a valid user or not. To distinguish administrators from normal users, you need to enter the authorization phase and ASP.NET has built in support for that kind of thing.

Comment: Precisely what @LexLi said, you may also be opening yourself up to attacks if you're not checking user roles on `POST` requests, we obviously don't know your exact implementation so far but the fact that you could be opening yourself up to real security risks is another reason why you should look into what's being suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your reply in comments...

> we read users permissions on sign on.when i use User.Identity.IsAuthenticated then its return true.but this Authenticated for admin.how to make different Authenticated for users?

Checking whether a user is authenticated is different from checking a user's permissions. Authentication only tells you that the person visiting your site has authenticated themselves (i.e. logged on to their account).

What's missing in your equation is the authorization phase (Remember college/uni? Everyone is issued ID cards, on access to the college/uni grounds you authenticate yourself, staff members also authenticate themselves, students won't have authorization to enter the staff room or perform certain tasks, but staff members do).

We implement this using what's called `Roles`, every user should have a `Role`. Every `Role` should have a set of `Permissions` associated with it, for now I wouldn't worry about `Permissions` as it can get real complicated real quick, if you focus on ìmplementing roles alone for now, it would be enough to get you going.

Once every user has a role associated to their account, you can check their `Role`  instead of whether they're simply authenticated, which doesn't tell you much.

There should be an extension method to the `IPrinciple` interface along the lines of `GetUserRoles()` already implemented in framework, `User.Identity.GetUserRoles()` something along the lines of that.